# Nominatim disk space Needed for whole planet-osm

Tags: installation, nominatim

How much disk space needed for installing planet-osm Nominatim file ?

After trying to install nominatim with planet-latest.osm.pbf I got this error:

```
Done 15249 in 44 @ 346.568176 per second - Rank 26 ETA (seconds): 80273.023438
index_placex: UPDATE failed: ERROR:  could not extend file "base/32849/1731142": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

I have a SSD hard-disk with 1.2T

```
df -h /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main 
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5d9be0b7-27a3-4085-837f-a96ae3c2400b  1.1T  1.1T     0 100% /
```

Is there temporary tables that I can removed in order to make some free place ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am posting the answer of my question for who need...

The disk space needed for whole planet is ~759G.

During the installation I face to disk space memory (see my post). After some check it came from logs (syslog.log and kernel.log ) that took a LOT of space (more than 400G). To avoid this issue I change the logrotate conf (and set the max size to 100M) and create a script that call logrotate every 1 min (after 1 min the logs have a size of 200M) in background.

Here the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf 
    rm -f /var/log/*.1
    sleep 60
done
```

I stop the script after the install.